# Deleting rows - using join vs in, when duplicate rows would be returned in join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sample code:

```
create table t1 (id int not null primary key, name varchar(10))    
insert t1 values (1, 'one')
insert t1 values (2, 'two')
insert t1 values (3, 'three')    

create table t2 (id2 int not null)    
insert t2 values (2)
insert t2 values (2)
go

select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id2  -- S1: returns 2 rows
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select t2.id2 from t2)  -- S2: returns 1 row
go
-- only run D1 or D2, not both
delete t1 from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id2  -- D1
delete t1 from t1 where t1.id in (select t2.id2 from t2)  -- D2
```

The line marked: S1 returns multiple rows as expected, whereas S2 returns only 1, since "IN" is used.

Now, when deleting, both D1 and D2 seem to work (i.e. no error reported). 
With D1, it seems SQL server internally does something like a DISTINCT on the id before deleting (?). 
My question is, are D1 and D2 functionally equivalent in situations like this.

Comment: I believe that SQL Server will only perform delete operations on the first target table, which in both cases would be `t1`.  If a given record appears more than once, it does not change anything.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [`Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states: "FROM _table_source_: Specifies an additional FROM clause. This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE allows specifying data from <table_source> and deleting the corresponding rows from the table in the _first FROM clause_." _(Emphasis mine.)_ `delete from t1 from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id2` and `delete from t1 from t2 join t1 on t1.id = t2.id2` both do the same thing. The _first FROM_ refers to having the keyword `FROM` used twice in one statement.

Comment: @HABO Good link, too bad it doesn't also address the issue of the row being duplicated by the join.

Comment: @Moe Sisko what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Eli delete the rows in table t1 where t1.id matches t2.id2 . Both D1 and D2 seem to work ok to do this. The question was more academic - I was not sure initially if D1 would work - because of the duplicate rows resulting from the join.

Comment: Since there is no issue with `delete from Foo where Bar = 42;` regardless of the number of matching values (Zero, one or more.), or `delete from Foo where Bar in ( 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 );`, I wouldn't expect duplicate rows to cause a problem. The "first" hit deletes the target row and subsequent hits on the same row delete zero rows. No error, just a value in `@@RowCount` that should match the count of `distinct` rows to be deleted.